# HP Proliant 380 G4 iLO stuck in recovery mode

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, ilo

The iLO interface on this server is stuck in recovery mode.  I've tried flashing the firmware via FTP per the iLO manual.  It seems like the flash succeeds & the iLO interface resets, but it comes back up in recovery mode.  System Management Homepage doesn't see the Management Processor & (needless to say) hponcfg doesn't either.  Is there anything else I can try to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Old server. Is there any chance you've had system board issues previously? Have you looked at the motherboard battery?

Comment: It's going to be decommissioned soon & I don't want to replace the motherboard if I don't have to.  SIM reports everything else is fine, so I think the mobo batt is prob OK.

Comment: Try clearing NVRAM, checking the system maintenance DIP switches and removing power for an extended period of time and powering back on.